# Laravel blade hide select options in foreach loop

Tags: php, laravel

Hi I'm trying to show/hide select options in blade view in Laravel.

im passing in the Model ($assessments) to the view:

```
[{"id":1,"user_id":1,"name":"Appointment 1","created_at":"2018-03-31 00:00:00","updated_at":"2018-03-31 00:00:00"},{"id":2,"user_id":1,"name":"Appointment 2","created_at":"2018-03-31 00:00:00","updated_at":"2018-03-31 00:00:00"}]
```

In the view I've got:

```
<select name="assessment" required>
                <option selected>Select...</option>
                @foreach($assessments as $assessment)

                    @if ($assessment->name == 'Appointment 1')
                        <option value="Appointment 1">Appointment 1</option>
                    @endif

                    @if ($assessment->name == 'Appointment 2')
                        <option value="Appointment 2">Appointment 2</option>
                    @endif

                    @if ($assessment->name == 'Appointment 3')
                        <option value="Appointment 3">Appointment 3</option>
                    @endif

                @endforeach
                <option value="Follow Up Phone Call">Follow Up Phone Call</option>
                <option value="Home Assessment">Home Assessment</option> -->
            </select>
```

If the if statement equals to True, I don't know if you can put a continue to bypass in the foreach loop? otherwise, it displays values mulitple times from loop.

Answer (score 1):

Let's assume that in the controller, you have got your results and put it in `$assesments` variable. One thing you can do is that you can define a new array and send it to your view:

```
$assesmentNames = [];
foreach($assesments as $assesment) {
  $assesmentNames[$assesment->name] = $assesment->name;
}
return view('myview', compact('assesments', 'assesmentNames'));
```

Now automatically the duplicates are gone. Then do this in your view:

```
@foreach($assessmentNames as $assessmentName)
  <option value="{{ $assessmentName }}"> {{ $assessmentName }} </option>
@endforeach
```

Comment: Thank you this is really great. But I'm looking to hide the selected option that was picked in the view? So if you picked "Appointment 1" it would be hidden in the select option next time.

Comment: I've done it now, cheers :-) I just unset the selected option from the array.

Comment: @Chev Glad to hear that :)

Answer (score 0):

your may use "continue" statement in simple php tags within loop if you want to skip the particular iteration